# Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
function(){
           setTimeout(function (){
        $('#refresh').html('<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/bg/plovdiv/49959/weather-forecast/49959" class="aw-widget-legal"></a><div id="awcc1400681634150" class="aw-widget-current"  data-locationkey="49959" data-unit="c" data-language="bg-bg" data-useip="false" data-uid="awcc1400681634150"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script></div>');
        },900);
    }
    );
```

I dont get it why it give me every time this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
on this row

```
$('#refresh').html('<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/bg/plovdiv/49959/weather-forecast/49959" class="aw-widget-legal"></a><div id="awcc1400681634150" class="aw-widget-current"  data-locationkey="49959" data-unit="c" data-language="bg-bg" data-useip="false" data-uid="awcc1400681634150"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script></div>');
```

Comment: You have extra `);` at the end. You can either remove it or if you want to call it immediately, to add `(` before function and add () before `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `</script>` in your string. You will have to escape that `"<\/script>"` or put it differently `"</ + script>"`

Comment: That's correct, only the closing `script` tag needs to be escaped